# C programming why does the address of char array increment from 0012FF74 to 0012FF75?

Tags: c

Heres the code:

```
    char chararray[] = {68, 97, 114, 105, 110}; 
    /* 1 byte each*/
    int i;
    printf("chararray intarray\n");
    printf("-------------------\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    printf("%p\n", (chararray + i));
```

Output:

```
    chararray
    ---------
    0012FF74
    0012FF75
    0012FF76
    0012FF77
```

Now im trying to understand this in terms of hexadecimal, bits and bytes.

I understand that a char is 1 byte and its supposed to increment by 1 byte which is 8 bits.

But I dont understand how its only increasing by 1 in hex? 1 hexadecimal only represents 4 bits correct? so Im kind of confused, it seems like its only incrementing by 4 bits.

Any help on clearing this up is greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: In hexadecimal, the value is given by the sum of the ith bit multiplied by 16^(i-1). So the first bit (starting from right) adds a value of 1, not 16.

Comment: Note: to avoid undefined behavior, the argument type that goes with a `%p` must be a ptr-to-void: `printf("%p\n", (void *)(chararray + i));`

Comment: Hex is just a way of writing numbers... If you increase a number by 1 then it increases by 1 in hex, in decimal, in octal, or in whatever.

Answer (score 1):

It's true that if you represent a byte in hexa then it is made out of 2 hexa digits where each one stands for 4 bits.
However, the addresses you are seeing are addresses of bytes, and not the content of them. Each byte receives its own address, and the addresses are sequential, just like if we gave each byte a number: byte 0, byte 1, byte 2, byte 3,....

Answer (score 1):

The address in a pointer points to a *byte*, not to a *bit*.  Your pointer is of type `char *`, so when it is incremented, the address increases by `sizeof(char)`. If, however, you used a different type, such as `int`, your pointer would increase by `sizeof(int)` on each increment, even if it is pointing to a `char []` array.

On my machine, `sizeof(int)==4`, for example.

I wrote this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "ACBDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int *a = str;
    printf("Char\tAddr\n");
    while(a <= &str[25])
    {
        printf("%c\t%p\n", *a, (void *)a);
        a++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Char    Addr
A       00D5F9BC
E       00D5F9C0
I       00D5F9C4
M       00D5F9C8
Q       00D5F9CC
U       00D5F9D0
Y       00D5F9D4
```

Every fourth character in the string is outputted.

Answer (score 1):

First, pointer arithmetics like `(chararray + i)`, where `chararray` points to a `char` (i.e. is of type `char*`) increases the value of pointer `chararray` by `i * sizeof(char)`. Note that `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition.

Second, a pointer represents a memory address, which is represented by an integral value that indicates a position in an (absolutely or relatively) addressed memory block, e.g. on the heap, on the stack, on some other data segment, ... . Confer, for example, the following statement in this [online C standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> 6.3.2.3 Pointers
>
> (5) An integer may be converted to any pointer type. ...
>
> (6) Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. ...

So when viewing the value of a pointer, we can think of an integral value, just like `256` or `1024` (when "viewed" in decimal format), or `0x100` or `0x400` (when viewed in hexadecimal format). Note that `256` in decmial is equivalent to `100` in hexadecimal, and this has nothing to do with bits and bytes.

Adding `1` to an integral value of `256` (or 0x100) gives `257` (or 0x101), regardless of whether this value stands for a position in a memory block or for oranges sold in the department store. So it's all about "outputting" integral values in hex format.

See the following code illustrating this:

```
int main()
{
    char chararray[] = {68, 97, 114, 105, 110};
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        char *ptr = (chararray + i);
        unsigned long ptrAsIntegralVal = (unsigned long)ptr;
        printf("ptr: %p; in decmial format: %lu\n", ptr, ptrAsIntegralVal);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ptr: 0x7fff5fbff767; in decmial format: 140734799804263
ptr: 0x7fff5fbff768; in decmial format: 140734799804264
ptr: 0x7fff5fbff769; in decmial format: 140734799804265
ptr: 0x7fff5fbff76a; in decmial format: 140734799804266
ptr: 0x7fff5fbff76b; in decmial format: 140734799804267
```

Answer (score 0):

Using hexadecimal numbers is just another way of representing any number. It has nothing to do with bits and bytes. One byte is 8 bits, no matter if you represent it as hexadecimal number or decimal number. So it just increases by one = 1 Byte = 8 Bits.